# Azure Logic App: Terraform not detecting changes

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm

Terraform is not detecting changes made manually in logic app workflow after its deployment. Is it me or this is not yet possible with terraform?

The goal would be to detect them and redeploy if necessary

Comment: you have to give more details about "logic app workflow", so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terraform uses state to keep track of the state of your cloud resources.

It does not query your cloud resources each time. Therefore, any changed made manually will not be overwritten at once.

If you make a change to your Terraform template, it will be reapplied and the manual changes will be lost.

https://www.terraform.io/language/state/purpose